# Grunt Assemble: Multiple Distributions

Tags: gruntjs, assemble

We're working on an assemble project that will require some shared layouts and some custom layouts.

Originally we had one destination for the default pages. Now we're breaking that out so each brand/site gets their own distribution folder.

My question is - before we broke things out everything assembled correctly. Now that we have multiple distributions, things are getting a little confusing :)

Current setup:

templates

```
  |-- templates
  |  |-- _default
  |  |  |--includes
  |  |  |--layouts
  |  |  |--pages
  |  |-- brand 1
  |  |  |--includes
  |  |  |--layouts
  |  |  |--pages
  |  |-- brand 2
  |  |  |--includes
  |  |  |--layouts
  |  |  |--pages
```

Our assemble task:

```
    assemble: {
        options: {
        flatten: true,
        production: false,
        postprocess: require('pretty'),

    // Metadata
    pkg: '<%= pkg %>',
    site: '<%= site %>',

    // Templates
    // partials: '<%= site.includes %>',
    // layoutdir: '<%= site.layouts %>',
    // layout: '<%= site.layout %>'
  },
    brand1: {
      files: {'<%= site.justin %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/justin/**/*.hbs']}
    },
    brand2: {
      files: {'<%= site.jow %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/jow/**/*.hbs']}
    },
    tonylama: {
      files: {'<%= site.tonylama %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/tonylama/**/*.hbs']}
    },
    brand3: {
      files: {'<%= site.nocona %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/nocona/**/*.hbs']}
    },
    brand4: {
      files: {'<%= site.chippewa %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/chippewa/**/*.hbs']}
    }
}
```

So the question becomes - how do we successfully assemble to multiple distributions? Can you place `options` and point to their respective layout(s) and includes?

When I run a grunt assemble:brandname I get an error `Warning: Layout file (forgot-password.hbs) not found`

Answer (score 1):

The obvious thing that would be causing the error is that your layout is commented out. Barring that, you should be able to do:

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    flatten: true,
    production: false,
    postprocess: require('pretty'),

    // Metadata
    pkg: '<%= pkg %>',
    site: '<%= site %>',

    // Templates
    partials: '<%= site.includes %>',
    layoutdir: '<%= site.layouts %>',
    layout: '<%= site.layout %>'
  },
  justin: {
    options: {layout: 'justin/layout.hbs'},
    files: {
      '<%= site.justin %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/justin/**/*.hbs']
    }
  },
  jow: {
    options: {layout: 'jow/layout.hbs'},
    files: {
      '<%= site.jow %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/jow/**/*.hbs']
    }
  },
  tonylama: {
    options: {layout: 'tonylama/layout.hbs'},
    files: {
      '<%= site.tonylama %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/tonylama/**/*.hbs']
    }
  },
  nocona: {
    options: {layout: 'nocona/layout.hbs'},
    files: {
      '<%= site.nocona %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/nocona/**/*.hbs']
    }
  },
  chippewa: {
    options: {layout: 'chippewa/layout.hbs'},
    files: {
      '<%= site.chippewa %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/chippewa/**/*.hbs']
    }
  }
}
```

That said, as you scale things up it's going to get more difficult to manage - as you would expect. Another option is to create a plugin that automatically generates a "target" (http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#task-configuration-and-targets) for each brand.

Comment: Helps to read the Docs (ugh) :P. I noticed the options: {} can be added to task OR targets. This is helping. Actually assembled the full site for one of the brands! The only issue that came out of that was Assembling _dist/_justin/cancel-order.html ERROR
Warning: The partial body could not be found Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.

Comment: @SalBaldovinos are you using `{{>body}}` in your layouts? I thought we updated to the regex to check for `{{>body}}` or `{{body}}` (but we might have removed the `{{>body}}` syntax completely). We aren't using actual partials for it now, so it might be useful to know what version of assemble you're using and see one of your layouts.

Comment: Yea, I'm using {{> body}} didnt know there was another way. Either way - it's working now.

Answer (score 0):

Using the options inside the target, I was able to fix my errors and push to multiple dist folders.

```
assemble: {
  options: {
    flatten: true,
    production: false,
    postprocess: require('pretty'),

    // Metadata
    pkg: '<%= pkg %>',
    site: '<%= site %>',
  },
    brand: {
      options: {
        //Template Config
        partials: '<%= site.brandIncl %>',
        layoutdir: '<%= site.brandLayouts %>',
        layout: '<%= site.brandLayout %>'
      },
      files: {'<%= site.brand %>/': ['<%= site.templates %>/brand/pages/*.hbs']}
    }
```